# CakePHP Routing and named parameters

Tags: php, cakephp, parameters, routes

I have the following route:

```
Router::connect('/admin/login/:to',
                array('admin'=>true,'controller'=>'users','action'=>'login'),
                array(
                    'to' => '[A-Za-z0-9\._-]+',
                    'pass' => array('to')
                ));
```

Which basically passes a string/int with the login url. But it no longer uses the named parameter of to. So for example instead of getting: `/admin/login/to:1AB` I get `/admin/login/1AB`

How do I keep the named parameter but still alter the routing to remove the users bit from the url? I've tried: `'/admin/login/to::to'` but that seems rather sloppy...

Comment: Try using `Router::connectNamed()`

Comment: Could you show an example of how I would use that with MY route please as I have never heard of `connectNamed` before and not sure if I use it with or instead of `connect`. Cheers

Comment: `Router::connectNamed(array("to"))`

Answer (score 0):

Remove that route. Why do you have that route when you want the named parameter?

Edit: if so:

```
Router::connect(
    '/admin/login/*',
    array(
        'admin'      => true,
        'controller' => 'users',
        'action'     => 'login'
    )
);
```

Comment: As I want to remove the controller name from the url and just have the prefix, action and the named parameter!

Answer (score 0):

you could find passed parameter's name in "$this->data" in your controller.
in your example: $this->data->to has the same value you put in your url.